# Form groups computing max - min depending on number of peers

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, max

This is table:

```
CREATE table point (
         datetime timestamp,
         value float)
```

I have data in some range of time

```
7:00 - 7:15:   0   5 : 5

7:15 - 7:30:   -   - : null

7:30 - 7:45:   7   - : 2


INSERT INTO point values ('2011-01-01 07:01:00', 0);
INSERT INTO point values ('2011-01-01 07:14:00', 5);
INSERT INTO point values ('2011-01-01 07:31:00', 7);
```

This is the the query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', datetime) - ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM 
      datetime)::int) % 15) * interval '1 minute', 
    MAX(value) - MIN(value)
    from point
    where datetime BETWEEN '2011-01-01 07:00:00' and '2011-01-01 07:45:00'
    group by 1
```

This is the current result:

```
2011-01-01 07:00:00 |        5
2011-01-01 07:30:00 |        0
```

My expect result is:

```
2011-01-01 07:00:00 |        5
2011-01-01 07:30:00 |        2
```

The second result I want is 7 - (5 - 0) = 2. If previous time also has only one value, it also should be 7 - (5 - 0) = 2.

Comment: Please it is not clear, can you add a sample using some fiddle like [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6) with a create table and insert statement?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Stop and delete what you've got. Show us the actual data. Preferably with INSERT and CREATE TABLE statements. Then show us what you want.

Comment: What if the previous range also has only 1 value? Your question remains ambiguous. Table definitions and Postgres version are minimum requirements for this.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my unclear post. I added the table, insert and results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly ...

Use a subquery and compute the value depending on the count of rows.
Then get the final result using the [window function **`lag()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT time_interval
     , CASE WHEN ct > 1 THEN span ELSE span - lag(span) OVER (ORDER BY time_interval) END AS span
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('minute', datetime) - ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime)::int) % 15) * interval '1 minute' AS time_interval
        , CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN MAX(value) - MIN(value) ELSE MAX(value) END AS span
        , count(*) AS ct
   FROM   point
   WHERE  datetime BETWEEN '2011-01-01 07:00:00' and '2011-01-01 07:45:00'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
```